# Configuration of services via Systemd for Embedded Linux

Tags: network-manager, services, systemd, time, embedded-system

Hello Dear Ubuntu Users,

I am working on an embedded system, which runs Ubuntu.

The task I would like to achieve; after the deployment of the machine, shut the network services for 15 minutes (let's say `shutUp` command).

Up to now, it seems straightforward. The tricky part is, when we have working network services we may send a command like 'reboot'.

Here is my question, how can I exclude `shutUp` command for each reboot, and make it work just for the first boot?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. Boot will be triggered by a mechanical setting during deployment that starts machine's clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Elesmoth, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

In `man systemd.unit`, you'll find the official docs for `ConditionFirstBoot=`, which exists for just this case.

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, you can easily provide the logic you need yourself.

Have the `shutUp` command set to start always on boot. It will immediately check to see if a "first boot" file exists. If the file exists, the script will stop. If the file does not exist, it will run it's action and create the file.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer was helpful, please upvote it and mark it as "Accepted".